# Minecraft: Display Player gamemode (in game) using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have searched and researched.  I do **not** need to know **how** to set gamemode.

I would need to display (or list) the gamemode of each player in the game from the command line.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Server:  MC 1.9.4, spigot

Comment: @Rudolf Bold is not a requirement.  In fact, it often makes things worse.  It does not help make readability better.

Comment: thanks I will keep that in mind.  My use of bold stems for the fact that helpers (often) tell me to do things that I already know, tried and/or were not part of the question.   It happens often.    I guess bold is offensive?

Comment: That was directed towards the previous editor, not yourself; bold *can* help, in some cases, but most often, it actually detracts from readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a scoreboard set up to do this:

Base scoreboard command:

```
/scoreboard objectives add GM dummy Player_Gamemode
```

Then you set up a redstone clock. This will repeat as often as possible:

(IN COMMAND BLOCKS)

```
/scoreboard players set @a[m=0] GM 0
/scoreboard players set @a[m=1] GM 1 
/scoreboard players set @a[m=2] GM 2
/scoreboard players set @a[m=3] GM 3
```

Finally, do:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar GM
```

Comment: Very nice.  I like it.  I will give that try.  tks.

Comment: I just finished this and it is perfect!   Huge Thanks.  :)

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, be sure to give it a check. :D Great to hear you like it

Comment: does this method still compatible with 1.16 version?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using the `/say` command in this way:

> /say @a Status: @a[m=0] is/are in survival mode
>
> /say @a Status: @a[m=1] is/are in Creative mode

`m=M` is the gamemode entity selector argument. Instead of M put 0 for Survival, 1 for Creative, 2 for Adventure and 3 for Spectator mode.

**Note**: I have not tested this, so my syntax could be wrong. Please fix me if it is wrong.

Comment: That helped.  this works...   /say @e[type=Player,m=1]

Comment: I'm in gamemode 1 and My name was listed.

Comment: `/say` does not take a player argument, so the first `@a` is just going to display the names of all players. The syntax is just `/say <message>`