# Is there a programmatic way to retrieve a player's current gamemode using the @minecraft/server module and WITHOUT using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons, minecraft-behavior-packs

In my custom tools addon, I've noticed a bug where you can get negative durability values by using the tool in creative mode, then switching to survival mode. This is because while vanilla tools don't take durability damage when used in creative mode, the custom ones do. I'd like to be able to reproduce the vanilla tool functionality by having my decrement-durability function be called *conditionally* only when the player is not in creative mode.

**But, I haven't found any way of detecting which game mode is active within the `main.js` file.**

I'm aware of how to detect players' game modes using command blocks, as discussed in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266917/minecraft-display-player-gamemode-in-game-using-commands), and also how to *set* the game mode using [this command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/commands/commands/gamemode?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable). And, I have found the documentation page for the [GameMode enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server/gamemode?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable) in the `@minecraft/server` module, which lists all the possible modes. I would have expected there to be a way of finding which one is active, but if so it's not documented there.

There doesn't seem to be a `getCurrentGameMode()` method or anything similar for either the [World](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server/world?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable) or [Player](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server/player?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable) classes.

I guess it is probably possible to do something like programmatically place a command block and set its command, then set up a chain command block in 'conditional' mode that places a certain type of block only if the 'test for player in creative mode' command returned true, and then have the script check for that special type of block before replacing all three with air. But, I'd really prefer not to use a workaround like this.

So, is there a way of detecting the active game mode using *only* script functions, that does not require placing temporary blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of **@minecraft/server** version **1.10.0-beta**, it is now possible to access the game mode programmatically using the new `.getGameMode()` method of the `Player` object.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server/player?view=minecraft-bedrock-experimental#getgamemode